# Is it practical to find travel insurance that has no alcohol-related exclusions?

Tags: insurance, australian-citizens, alcohol

[CHOICE travel insurance buying guide](http://smartraveller.gov.au/guide/all-travellers/insurance/pages/choice-travel-insurance-buying-guide.aspx) mentions alcohol-related exclusions for insurance:

> Alcohol
>
> Cover for overdoing it on vodka and Red Bull and float-tubing down a
>   river in Laos isn't included in any policy. Insurers simply won't pay
>   for costs arising from you being under the influence of alcohol or a
>   drug (except where taken under the advice of a doctor).
>
> Case study: Jenny*
>
> Jenny was nightclubbing with friends in Bali, Indonesia, when she
>   became ill after drinking a cocktail. Her friends recognised the
>   symptoms of methanol poisoning and rushed her to hospital.
>
> Fortunately, Jenny recovered after two weeks of care. But because she
>   had been drinking alcohol at the time she was poisoned, her insurer
>   refused to pay the claim.
>
> Jenny's cash-strapped family had to sell their car to pay the $25,000
>   in medical expenses.

[Alcohol and travel insurance: how does drinking impact your cover?](https://www.finder.com.au/alcohol-travel-insurance) has a look at various travel insurance policies, and lists alcohol-related exclusions for them. For what it's worth, it mentions that just because a company has an exclusion, it's not necessarily a blanket exclusion, such as Southern Cross Travel Insurance (expanded on in their blog post [They say "Nothing good happens after midnight!"](https://www.scti.co.nz/travel-insurance/travel-blog/after-midnight-travel-tips/)).

I'm aware of the risks of excessive drinking, and I'm not a big drinker - I'm often the only person in a gathering that isn't drinking, but I occasionally have a foreign drink or two when travelling, such as sake or plum wine.

Is it practical to find travel insurance for Australians that has no alcohol-related exclusions at all?

Comment: Depends on the country perhaps? (+1 in any case)

Comment: @Relaxed oops, fixed.

Comment: Would you be interested in policies that differentiate between drinking (say one or two drinks), and being inebriated? (I don't have an answer; I'm just also curious after reading your question!)

Comment: I once had a policy that excluded anything that happened if you *or anyone you were with* was under the influence of drugs or alcohol. So get mugged walking back from dinner, totally sober, but your mate had a beer? Out of luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Alcohol exclusions are standard in all widely available travel insurance policies, for at least denial of boarding and injury but possibly also for damage. For a sufficient premium almost all future eventualities are insurable but a policy for a specific individual cannot be considered practical even if the premium is less than the maximum sum insured.